# How to setup ingress for Azure Kubernetes cluster using AGIC?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-application-gateway

I have two applications that I want to deploy to my cluster, and thought that I could prefix them in the ingress with different paths to reach them.

When I setup the first application using the below setup everything works as expected, I can reach the application using the public IP of the application gateway and navigate it:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: store-front
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-path-prefix: "/"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Exact
        backend:
          service:
            name: store-front
            port:
              number: 80
```

But when I try to add my second application in the mix I want to update the first application to use a specific path, for example `/store`.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: store-front
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-path-prefix: "/"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /store
        pathType: Exact
        backend:
          service:
            name: store-front
            port:
              number: 80
```

My problem now is that only the first request works, so going to `<PUBLIC_IP>/store` gives me the page but all sub sequent requests from the application are now wrong, since they do not use the prefix of `/store`. So all css and js requests break.

So my question is if there is a way to handle this in the ingress and not in the application (as if I don't have access to modify the routing in the app)?

Can I setup the ingress to make/force all sub sequent requests from the application somehow use the `/store` prefix?

I have also tried this (that I saw was suggested when others have asked similar questions) without any luck getting it registered in my application gateway backend pool.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: store-front
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /store(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Exact
        backend:
          service:
            name: store-front
            port:
              number: 80
```

I assume this does not work since it is not the appgw.ingress annotation and thus not supported.

Comment: See if this helps- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/ingress-controller-install-existing and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/tutorial-ingress-controller-add-on-new#deploy-a-sample-application-by-using-agic

To handle routing for multiple applications using different paths, you can use the path field in the spec.rules.http.paths section of the Ingress resource.

Comment: This is the documentation I have read and followed, doesn't work as I had hoped.

Answer (score 0):

I find your statement `that only the first request works`, which pretty much looks like "health probe down" issue.

There is a statement in official document as below:

> If the above probes aren't provided, then the Ingress Controller makes an assumption that the service is reachable on the `Path` specified for `backend-path-prefix` annotation, or the `path` specified in the `ingress` definition for the service.

See also: [Add Health Probes to your service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/ingress-controller-add-health-probes#without-readinessprobe-or-livenessprobe)

Since you have `appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-path-prefix: "/"`, I suggest you make sure there will be `200/ok` response code returned from the path `/`.
**In simple:** set up any normal page behind the path `/`, and even blank page will work, as long as it returns `200/ok` response code.
**Note:** cannot be the return code like `404`.

Also, do check out "health probe" in application gateway to verify the root cause. See also: [Application Gateway health probes overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-probe-overview#probe-operations)

Comment: The thing is that only the initial request works, so the issue is that the subsequent requests made from the application will not use the path prefix of the first request. Thus the initial health probe request is ok and the application/pod starts. But seems I need to have access to modify the application routing so that it is aware of the path prefix, as in hardcoded/part of the configuration.

Comment: @KungWaz The health probe does not work like this. Since you are using application gateway, the health probe status is determined by Azure application gateway. So it is possible you can access the backend before the health probe block the backend. (BTW this also can happen on unmanaged nginx ingress controller, but it's a different thing blocking it.)

Comment: Ok, good to know, but I think I was unclear with my statement "the initial request works". What I mean is the first request were I enter the prefix in the path, for example "mysite.com/store" always returns 200 OK, but there are no styles nor scripts working because the sub sequent requests use "mysite.com/styles.css" and not "mysite.com/store/styles.css". So I can always, even after an hour, access the "mysite.com/store" page, it is not getting blocked. So it is related to the routing, and the question is if I can handle that in the ingress instead of in the app? Hope it is more clear now :)